# Sending an image from android to wamp server

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a PNG image from android device to wamp server running in my laptop. Following is the code I've used for AsyncTask.

```
public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap image;
        String name;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList();
        Bitmap SendImg1;

        public UploadImage(String rc){

            int w,h;
            name = rc;

            try{
                SendImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(name);
                w = SendImg1.getHeight();
                Integer i = new Integer(w);
                String s = i.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "rc is " + rc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name is " + rc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in constructor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            image = SendImg1;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside OnPreEXEC" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVERADDRESS + "/SavePicture.php");


            try{    
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside try block of Onpostexec",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            client.execute(post);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside try block after client.execute(post) ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem in doinBG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


            return null; 
        }//doinBackground ends

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside onpost exec",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // code from BG starts here



            // code from BG ends here



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image sent to the server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
```

While running the application in android device my phone is still in USB connection with laptop- I hope this is not a problem. 
I have connected my laptop and android device by tethering through a third device which is also a phone.

At many places I have put the toast message to check the reachability of the code. In the try catch block of doInBackground() , the second toast message i.e., after

```
    client.execute(post);
```

is not coming. So I feel that I may have gone wrong in this line, but not able to figure out exactly how?

Comment: That code is doing to many things for testing it. I recommend you to remove some stuff. Start by posting a simple string and check the backend is receiving it. When done, add an string as a dummy image and later check the encoding logic for the image is working too.

Comment: You cannot call Toast() in the doInBackground() of an AsyncTask. Your app will crash immediately. But you did not report a crash! Change them to Log.d() statements. After you did that change the code here too.

Comment: Got it... The problem was in timeout delay...I just had to increase it... But receiving a blank image with zero bytes.. What might have gone wrong